# passing multi dimensional array from multiple option box into mysql

Tags: php, html, mysql

any help would be much appreciated.

I have a select/option box passing a `$_GET` array into a php controller that passes this value into a model retrieving some MySQL.

However I am up to the stage where I am just wishfully stabbing at this now. I think the problem is with the array though.

```
<select id="frm_type" style="margin-left:180px; width: 136px; height:100%;" name="uid[]" multiple="multiple">
    <option value="U4BC3128209B01">All Users</option>
    <option value="U4D88B8CFE7579">more options</option>        
</select>
```

The `$_GET` looks like this `?&uid%5B%5D=U4DFF15A4581A4&uid%5B%5D=U4D88B8CFE7579`
This comes into the controller like so...

`$filter_in = $_GET;`

then is called into the model like this.

`$body_data['user_stats'] = $this->mtvm_model->user_stats($filter_in);`

Then finally the relevant section that wants to use it does this:

```
        if ($filter_in['uid'] != '')
        {
        $sqlQuery .= " AND ";

        foreach($filter_in['uid'] as $key=>$value)
            {
            $sqlQuery .= " ".$this->tables_calls.".userId = '".mysql_real_escape_string($value)."' ";
            if($key != count($filter_in['uid'])-1) 
                {
                $sqlQuery .= " OR ";
                }
            }
        }
```

Is it simply that I am incorrectly trying to pass an array as `$filter_in['uid']`?

Comment: Are you sure the query string is like `&uid=U4BC3128209B01&uid=U4D88B8CFE7579` and not like `&uid%5B%5D=U4BC3128209B01&uid%5B%5D=U4D88B8CFE7579`?

Comment: sorry yep it is like that. I have literally copied n pasted the get from the url.

Comment: That is not possible. If your listbox has `name="uid[]"` then it should be submitted as `uid[]=&uid[]=` or `uid%5B%5D=&uid%5B%5D`. I suspect there is something wrong in your form.

Comment: my bad i have literall just checked.... ?cd=&dd=2012-11-01&uid%5B%5D=U4DFF15A4581A4&uid%5B%5D=U4D88B8CFE7579. ur totally correct.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The query string:

```
uid%5B%5D=U4DFF15A4581A4&uid%5B%5D=U4D88B8CFE7579
```

implies that `$_GET["uid"]` looks like this:

```
Array
(
    [0] => U4BC3128209B01
    [1] => U4D88B8CFE7579
)
```

Your should check for the presence of this variable like this:

```
if (isset($filter_in['uid']) && is_array($filter_in['uid'])) {
    // ...
```